# How to copy a read only file into google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I am trying to copy a file into google cloud storage through google cloud build using

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['cp', source, dest]
```

but I am getting the error "No URLs matched." I know the file exists in the source location, so I think the error is due to the file being read-only. Is there any way for me to get around this?

Comment: This error means that your source is not a file in Cloud Storage. If you are specifying a directory, then add `/*`' to the end to copy all files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions in that file or run the command as root, I add the link to how to copy files and objects.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp